# How to convert a for-loop into a producer?

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

There is a *SynchronousProducer* interface, that supports two operations:

```
public interface SynchronousProducer<ITEM> {
    /**
     * Produces the next item.
     *
     * @return produced item
     */
    ITEM next();

    /**
     * Tells if there are more items available.
     *
     * @return true if there is more items, false otherwise
     */
    boolean hasNext();
}
```

*Consumer* asks the producer if there are more items available and if none goes into a shutdown sequence.

**Now follows the issue.**

At the moment there is a *for-loop* cycle that acts as a producer:

```
for (ITEM item: items) {
  consumer.consume(item);
}
```

The task is to convert a controlling code into the following:

```
while (producer.hasNext()) {
  consumer.consume(producer.next())
}

consumer.shutdown();
```

**The question.** Given the *items*: how to write the producer implementing *SynchronousProducer* interface and duplicating the logic of the for-loop shown above?

Comment: What is `items` ? Is it a list maybe?

Comment: *Items* is just some *iterable* container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `items` implements `Iterable`, you can adapt it to your SynchronousProducer interface like this:

```
class IterableProducer<T> implements SynchronousProducer<T> {

    private Iterator<T> iterator;

    public IterableProducer(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        iterator = iterable.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return iterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }
}
```