# How to convert a method with a consumer argument into a producer?

Tags: java, producer-consumer, functional-interface

This question follows the previous one: [How to convert a for-loop into a producer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994150/how-to-convert-a-for-loop-into-a-producer?noredirect=1#comment107909847_60994150)

Underlying task (which is much more specific): [Reading a text file in the Producer paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008107/reading-text-file-in-a-producer-paradigm)

There is a *SynchronousProducer* interface, that supports two operations:

```
public interface SynchronousProducer<ITEM> {
    /**
     * Produces the next item.
     *
     * @return produced item
     */
    ITEM next();

    /**
     * Tells if there are more items available.
     *
     * @return true if there is more items, false otherwise
     */
    boolean hasNext();
}
```

*Consumer* asks the producer if there are more items available and if none goes into a shutdown sequence.

**Now follows the issue.**

At the moment there is a *currentProducer* object implementing the following interface:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public interface CurrentProducer<ITEM> {
    /**
     * Feeds data sequentially into consumer
     *   by calling {@link Consumer#accept} method on each data item.
     * @param consumer data consumer
     */
    void produce(Consumer<ITEM> consumer);
}

...

// controlling code:
currentProducer.produce(consumer);

consumer.shutdown();
```

The task is to convert the controlling code into the following:

```
var producer = new SynchronousProducerImpl(currentProducer);

while (producer.hasNext()) {
  consumer.accept(producer.next())
}

consumer.shutdown();
```

**The question.** Given the *currentProducer* that implements *CurrentProducer* interface: how to write the producer implementing *SynchronousProducer* interface? (It should wrap *currentProducer* object).

**Clarification.** There is a reasonable amount of questions coming from @Kayaman and it seems essential to add some clarity:

1. There is an existing codebase, that implements the *CurrentProducer* interface.
2. There is an ongoing refactoring aiming at encapsulating concurrency into a pipeline that schematically looks like that:

   ```
   pipeline
       .setProducer(producer)
       .setProcessor(processor)
       .setWriter(writer)
       .run();
   ```

The pipeline is responsible for managing stuff like task management, keeping a reasonable amount of workers active, suspending data production if processing can't keep pace and so on.

3. Now the issue at hand is to be able to wrap an existing codebase (that reads files essentially) so it could be plugged into the pipeline described above or make a decision to refactor it to comply with a "producer-paradigm" (sorry) as well.

**Update.** It seems that a more reasonable interface for producer should be as the following:

```
public interface SynchronousProducer<ITEM> {
    /**
     * Tries to produce the next item.
     *
     * @return true if item is successfully produced and false if items are exhausted
     * @throws ProductionException if item could not be produced.
     */
    boolean next() throws ProductionException;

    /**
     * Returns an item produced by {@link #next method}.
     *
     * @return item produced
     * @throws ProductionException if trying to retrieve an item that is not produced yet.
     */
    ITEM get() throws ProductionException;
}
```

Comment: What's a "functional consumer"? Your `SynchronousProducer` seems to be basically an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: @Kayaman I may not have chosen accurate terminology here, but what I mean is that I have a method, that takes a consumer interface as an argument and feeds data into it. I would like to write a producer, that wraps this method and conforms to the SynchronousProducer interface.

Comment: Well your terminology is confusing when you compare it to JDK's `Consumer`, `Producer` and `Function`, which are well defined. "Functional consumer acting as a producer" sounds like a weird combination of those three (although a function is essentially a producer and consumer put together). As for your question, how is it different from your last one? Show the code to your current `producer`.

Comment: @Kayaman You are right. Rewrote the question and hope it helps clarify the issue at the discussion.

Comment: We need to see the code for the current `producer` in order to help. Knowing the method signature isn't enough.

Comment: @Kayaman There is no code. It could be any code that implements the interface. Contract bounds it to feed items synchronously, that's all.

Comment: Well then you're basically changing code from `consumer.accept(someObject);` to `return someObject;` (and adding the `hasNext()`). It depends on how the producer gets hold of `someObject`. Very similar to your last linked question, in that case the producer gets `someObject` from a `List`. There's no "universal solution", it depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Kayaman Don't understand why is it so. *currentProducer* feeds data sequentially into a consumer calling *accept* method with a data item as an argument and then returns control. This behavior **does not** depend on implementation whatsoever. Now given the *currentProducer* with such a contract there is a problem to convert it into the *producer* following SynchronousProducer contact. It seems a sound and well-defined task.

Comment: @Kayaman Rewrote the question adding as much detail as possible. I hope it helps.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Or is the codebase written by someone who tried to show off and be clever (hence the "paradigm" you keep repeating). Are you trying to create simple code or complicated code? What is your [goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? If your **actual task** is to read a file, that's simple. If you have a school assignment for computer science, then this question makes sense.

Comment: As I said, it's not a problem to change `consumer.accept(obj);` to `return obj;`,  but the `hasNext();` depends on how the element comes into existence. Does it come from a collection, a file, from a blocking operation over a network, etc. so it **does** depend on the implementation.

Comment: If this is an actual business problem, and the problem is to read files, then go with `Stream`s. That's the simplest approach, lazy by default and numerous other advantages. It seems like there's a **lot** of over-engineering going on from your side. Duplicating the `Iterator` interface, inventing fancy "functional consumers acting as producers" and talking about paradigms, instead of solving your *business problem* in an efficient manner. You're succumbing to the XY problem by discussing your attempted solution, instead of accepting a simpler one.

Comment: @Kayaman It's not a school assignment. There is an existing codebase that is written in *CurrentProducer* terms. The task is to convert it into a *SynchronousProducer* kind of code to be able to plug it into a processing pipeline as a data-producing unit.

Comment: But you do realize that this changes the mode from a "push" to a "pull" type, and that's not as straight-forward as you claim. *Changing* the `CurrentProducer` would be simple, but you want to add another layer of abstraction. Not to mention that it's the `Consumer` that gets the elements. So you need access to that in order to be able to do anything.

Comment: @Kayaman Exactly. This issue occurred because the actual task is considerably easier formulated in the "pull" terms where the *pipeline (controller)* decides when it's ready to pull some more items from the producer to send them over to processing. Unfortunately, the current codebase if formulated in the "push" terms. Please see a post update for more details.

Comment: The problem is that if all you get is a `CurrentProducer`, you would need to intercept calls to `produce(Consumer)` to prevent the consumer from getting the elements. Regular proxying is probably out of the question at this point, so you'd need to resort to bytecode modification or some such. Although perhaps it would be more realistic to get rid of the "controller" that executes `currentProducer.produce(consumer);` as that doesn't make sense in a pipeline model anyway (see `InputStream`, `OutputStream`, `Stream` which are all examples of proper pipelines).

Comment: You're in a similar (except a bit more complicated) situation where you transfer data from `InputStream` to `OutputStream`, with your controller acting as the `IOUtils.copy(in, out);`. Your issue is getting access to the `out`, which in your case is the `consumer`. So a bigger refactoring may be needed just to get any code to even compile, let alone for the design to work.